# Moving connection string to environment variable now cause EF migrations to fail (connection string null)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

My project retrieves the connection string from environment variables both from the app service and the local project.

```
public static string GetConnectionStringFromEV()
{
    var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(EvCodes.AzureDb);
    if (AppConstants.DatabaseConstants.UseAzure == false)
    {
        if (Environment.MachineName == "CT-Machine1")
        {
            connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(EvCodes.CTDb);
        }
        if (Environment.MachineName == "FL-Machine1")
        {
            connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(EvCodes.FLDb);
        }
    }
    return connectionString is not null ? connectionString :"";
}
```

The app works fine in development and production (the connection string is in my app service EV's and my development environment EV's.

But I have now added a class to my domain model and when I tried to migrate, I get an error saying the connection string is null.

> > at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration. <>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> > at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
> > at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
> > The string argument 'connectionString' cannot be empty.

Googling the issue (connection strings from EV's) doesnt help much but some solutions revolved around an IDesignTimeDbContextFactory, so I built one based off the patterns I found and put it where I'm registering the db service

```
public static class DatabaseConfigurationRegistration
{
    public static IServiceCollection RegisterDatabaseConfiguration(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<RegistryDataContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<RegistryDataContext>();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        return services;
}

public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<RegistryDataContext>
{       
    public RegistryDataContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<RegistryDataContext>();
        var connectionString = UI_Services.Helpers.GetConnectionStringFromEV();
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new RegistryDataContext(builder.Options);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is I can't find anything on how to use it, nor am I even sure this will fix the original issue. (A null connection string while trying to add a new migration)

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory ("If a class implementing this interface is found in either the same project as the derived DbContext or in the application's startup project, the tools bypass the other ways of creating the DbContext and use the design-time factory instead."). So just put it where docs say and see if that helps (I expect it should help).

Comment: I tried putting it in both the startup and data access projects already, and no breakpoint in that method is ever hit.

Comment: And that article is where I got this idea from, I read it already.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `Package Manager Console` window to add migration then you can pass the connection string to the command that will pass it to the application:

```
Add-Migration NewMigrationName -Args "ConnectionStrings:YourKey=YourConnectionString"
```

Then in the design time factory you can read the command line arguments:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

IConfigurationRoot configuration =
    new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddCommandLine(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Skip(1).ToArray()))
        .Build();

string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("YourKey");
// connectionString will be "YourConnectionString"
```

Comment: my design time factory is in a class library, and I can add migrations, but there is no IConfiguration as it comes from the consuming application.  I can't tell from your answer where the ICongurationRoot line is . . . is it in the design time factory class, or is it in the startup code?

Comment: @PaulGibson, you can put these lines whereever it suits your needs. It can be in the class library as well. The command line arguments will be passed to the project you specify in the `-StartupProject` parameter for `Add-Migration` command but the code above will get them even if it is placed into the class library.